# How to add active class to link on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have below code and i want make the clicked link active. I tried different approaches but did not work.

```
 <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">  
    <ul class="list-group">  
      <a><li class="list-group-item active" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">A</li></a>  
      <a><li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">B</li></a>
        <a><li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">C</li></a>
    </ul>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Yeah, try using a valid HTML structure for start

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion...will try to add proper tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So First mistake here is:

its not a ideal approach to have a direct anchor in UL, You should use anchor inside LI. 
and then add class on clicked item and remove from all others
Check this example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.list-group-item').click(function(){
    $('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.list-group-item.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">  
    <ul class="list-group">  
      <li class="list-group-item active" style="background-color: #394263;color: white"><a>A</a></li>  
      <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white"><a>B</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white"><a>C</a></li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will keep in mind!!

Answer (score 0):

The generally recommended way to handle browser events in JavaScript is with [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and the best way I know to add/remove a class is with the [classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

**This simple demo shows how you can use them.**
(See the in-code comments, and possibly the linked MDN resources, for more info)

```js
// Identifies an HTML element
const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");

// Calls the `toggleBlue` function whenever the element is clicked
myDiv.addEventListener("click", toggleBlue);

// Defines the `toggleBlue` function
function toggleBlue(event){ // Listeners can access their triggering events
  const clickedThing = event.target; // Events have a `target` property

  // DOM elements have a `classList` property, which includes the
  //   methods `.contains`, `.remove`, and `.add`
  if(clickedThing.classList.contains("blue")){
    clickedThing.classList.remove("blue");
  }
  else{
    clickedThing.classList.add("blue");
  }
}
```

```css
#my-div{ width: 20ch; border: 1px solid grey; font-weight: bold; }
.blue{ color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="my-div">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you...Will surely try to adapt this...